# Java RMI and advanced multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, rmi

I am implementing something like a database where data manipulation statements (inserts, updates and deletes) get evaluated. Some statements can execute concurrently and others cannot (I compute that).  I like the ease of use and convenience of RMI, however I need to have a deeper understanding of the RMI service implementation w.r.t multithreading. For example,

1. Can the multithreading be controlled in any way?
2. Is a thread created for each remote call (on server side) or are thread pools used?
3. More generally, using RMI, how can I ensure that some rmi calls wait for other calls to terminate?
4. Is there another non-RMI approach, with the same convenience and efficiency that would work better for this?
5. If I want multi-threading should I just create threads myself on the server side code? The concern is that if the RMI Service creates multiple threads than I would be adding additional unnecessary threads.

If, for example, a thread is created on each call, then I can use the java join method to order the statement execution.  On the other hand, if thread pools are used then the join method won't work (since the threads don't terminate).

Comment: RMI is a communication layer and is not intrinsically tied to threading. Whether a new thread or pooled thread is used for each call is completely dependent on the RMI implementation. I think the reference implementation does the former. At any rate, a good thread pool implementation like `java.util.concurrent` will notify you of a thread task completion, usually via an `Executable` or `Future` interface or similar.
Last but not least I would suggest avoiding RMI as it is a very dated technology and using something more modern like a RESTful web service instead.

Comment: @sparc_spread IF RMI does not specify or allow for control of multi-threading on the server side, then it would appear to not  be suited for the DML application above, since I want concurrency. In other words its important to handle the calls concurrently.

Comment: If you want controlled concurrency, *control* it. Use the `synchronized` keyword, or semaphores. No mystery. At the most trivial level, make your remote methods `synchronized`.

Comment: 1. No. 2. It isn't relevant to your question. 3. Ditto. 4. No. It's already multithreaded. All you have to do is ensure appropriate synchronization at the server side. A single-threaded implementation of RMI is theoretcailly possible but it would be totally useless, and they don't exist.

Answer (score 1):

**Overview**

There seems to be a few questions within this post, so I will attempt to walk you through each portion in some detail.

**Question 1 - Can the multi-threading be controlled in any way?**

Yes! Your implementation of the multi-threading can be whatever you want it to be. A *RMI* implementation is only the communication between seperate JVMs with enough abstraction to feel like they exist on 1 JVM; thus has no effect on multi-threading as it is only the communication layer.

**Question 2 - Is a thread created for each remote call (on the server side) or are thread-pools used?**

See the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/rmi/spec/rmi-arch3.html). The short answer to if they are on separate threads is no.

> A method dispatched by the RMI runtime to a remote object implementation may or may not execute in a separate thread. The RMI runtime makes no guarantees with respect to mapping remote object invocations to threads. Since remote method invocation on the same remote object may execute concurrently, a remote object implementation needs to make sure its implementation is thread-safe.

*RMI* using thread-pools depends on the implementation, but as a developer utilizing *RMI* this should be of no concern as it is encapsulated in the *RMI* connection layer.

**Question 3 - Using *RMI*, how can I ensure that some *RMI* calls wait for other calls to terminate?**

This is a rather vague question, but I think what your asking is how do you properly block when synchronizing in *RMI*. This comes with your design of the application. Lets take the scenario where you are trying to access the database and you must synchronize *DB* access. If the client attempts to invoke access through *RMI*, it will invoke the remote server's method that holds all the synchronization, thus wait for a lock if it must. Therefore, the Client will be waiting for its turn to access the *DB* via the server. So, with your current scenario, you want your synchronization of the *DB* to be present on the **server-side**.

**Question 4 - Is there another non-RMI approach, with the same convenience and efficiency that would work better for this?**

Absolutely. Below is a brief list of communication implementations that could be utilized for communication.

1) RESTful

2) RMI

3) Sockets

4) gRPC

My recommendation is to utilize RESTful as it is the most straight-forward and has plenty of implementations/documentation on the internet. Efficiency seems to be quite a high concern for you, but your operations are only manipulating a DB in a standard manner. Therefore, I believe a Restful implementation would provide more than enough efficiency.

Think of it like this; you have N number clients, a load-balancer, and M servers. There exists no constant connection between clients and servers thus reducing complexity and computation. As N clients grows, the load balancer creates more instances of servers and allocating the load appropriately. Note, the requests between clients and servers are actually quite small as they will have a payload and a request type. Additionally, servers will receive the requests and compute the operations as normal and in parallel. The optimization can be done on the server side via threadpools or frameworks such as spring.

Comment: It would seem for the sake of efficiency that I would want to create multiple threads on the server side.  But  If the RMI implementation does not specify or allow that to be controlled then it would not be suitable for the DML application discussed above.

Comment: Regarding thee other approaches: RestFul - seems more suited for web based applications that use HTTP. Not sure it is efficient enough. Sockets: too low level although it would allow for more control of threading. Not sure about gRPC. How does it compare in efficiency to RMI?

Comment: Remember, try to separate RMI from multi-threading. They are two separate things. Just because the underlying implementation is one thing, doesn't mean your application cannot use thread-pools/multi-threading/etc. However, if you are looking to directly control the RMI implementation, you cannot.

Comment: So you are suggesting that I create the threads myself on the server side?  If the rmi server already does that than wouldn't that be redundant?

Comment: RMI handles connections. If you are worried about too many connections at a single time, then RMI may not be the solution. If you are utilizing multi-threading for the sake of minimizing computation time on the server-side, then implementing your own threads is fine and not redundant. RMI does not reduce computation time, its a connection implementation between 2 JVMs, thus multi-threading for the sake of optimization can be done in conjunction with it.

Comment: @danb RMI is just a communication mechanism (using sockets). You still have client and server components and client can call the server as and when you want (use multi threading etc). You are still the in charge of calling and handling the flow. IMO, I would prefer to use Rest/HTTP given the simplicity and abundance of frameworks/library available. RMI seems to be an out-dated technology and I don't think there is anything which a RMI based system can do which you cannot in a restful application.

Comment: @nrj Keep in mind that the remote call must return a result. So let's say the rmi implementation is single threaded. That would be bad because no statements could execute in parallel.  So just like with web servers, there should be a way to control the  number of threads in an RMI server.  Apparently that is not possible with current implementations?

Comment: @danb Its your choice on how you want to communicate and how much paralllelism you want. Example - on client side, an expected long running job can be done on a separate thread so that client is not blocked and can do another operation (may call another RMI operation). On server side, once you are there, you can launch as many threads you can support. One RMI call is however on a single thread but you can always do multiple calls.

Comment: @nrj If the rmi is single threaded it means that it does not generate a new thread per call. All other calls are blocked until the thread is done.  On the other hand if a new thread is generated per call (a multi-threaded implementation) that would be inefficient for a number of reasons (a thread pool is better). Furthermore, one would expect a  need to limit the number of simultaneous threads. The Oracle RMI implementation does not allow control of threads. The only other RMI implementation I could find is weblogic RMI which apparently allows the number of threads to be configured.

Comment: The short answer to if they are on separate threads is **YES.** The meaning of 'The RMI runtime makes no guarantees with respect to mapping remote object invocations to threads' is that you can't assume it is single-threaded. You have contradicted yourself several times on this point.

Comment: @user207421 For my own edification, can you clarify my contradictions?

Comment: @Impurity It is up to you to clarify your own contradictions, but if you mean 'point them out': 'A RMI implementation ... has no effect on multi-threading'; 'the short answer to if they are on separate threads is no'; 'RMI using thread-pools depends on the implementation ...  it is encapsulated in the RMI connection layer'; ...

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is a way to coordinate execution of the tasks according to their dependencies. The fact that your tasks make RMI calls is insignificant. We can imagine a pure computational tasks which does not access remote machines and still are dependent on each other, for example, by providing values computed in one task as parameters for other tasks.

The coordination of dependent tasks is the central problem of *asynchronous programming*. The support of asynchronous programming in JDK is not full but sufficient for your problem. You need to use 2 things: `CompletableFuture` and an `Executor`. Note that an RMI call blocks the thread it runs on, so using an Executor with limited number of threads can lead to the deadlock of specific kind, named "thread starvation", when the computation cannot move on because all available threads are blocked. So use an executor with unlimited number of threads, the simplest is the one which creates new thread for each task:

> ```
> Executor newThreadExecutor = (Runnable r)->new Thread(r).start();
> ```

Then, for each RMI call (or any other task), declare the task method. If the task does not depend on other tasks, then the method should have no parameters. If the task depends on the result(s) produced by other task(s), then declare one or two parameters (greater number of parameters is not supported  by CompletableFuture directly). Let we have:

```
String m0a() {return "ok";}  // no args
Integer m0b() {return 1;}  // no args
Double m2(String arg, Integer arg2) {return arg2/2.0;}  // 2 args
```

Let we want to compute the following result:

```
String r0a = m0a();
Integer r0b = m0b();
Double r2 = m2(r0a, r0b);
```

but asynchronously, so that calls to `m0a` and `m0b` are executed in parallel, and the call to `m2` starts as soon as both `m0a` and `m0b` finished.

Then, wrap each task method with an instance of `CompletableFuture` Depending on the signature of the task method, different methods of `CompletableFuture` are used:

```
 CompletableFuture<String> t0a = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(this::m0a, newThreadExecutor)
 CompletableFuture<Integer> t0b = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(this::m0b, newThreadExecutor)
 CompletableFuture<Double> t2 = t0a.thenCombineAsync(t0b, this::m2, newThreadExecutor)
```

The tasks start execution right after declaration, no call to special `start` method is required.

To get the final result from the last task `t2`, method `get()` of interface `Future` can be used:

```
 Double res = t2.get();
```

Comment: Overall, I am looking for the best approach to the DML problem. I am not really asking about how to coordinate dependencies, as I as aware of how to do that. Generally speaking since I want to execute DML statements concurrently, I want to execute each in a separate thread.  Imagine RMI is implemented whereby each call to a remote object executes in a new thread (or one obtained from a thread pool).  In such a case I may not need to generate threads myself.  Ideally it would seem to me that rmi should support multithreading just like http servers do.

Comment: @danb what is  "DML problem"?

Comment: Its what i reference in the first statement of the question.  DML stands for data manipulation statements.

Comment: @danb I cannot see any problem description in the first statement. I see something like this in the second statement, and described my solution how to make some statements to execute concurrently and others sequentially. That is, assume first that all tasks execute concurrently, and add dependencies between the tasks which should not execute concurrently. And I provided an Executor where "each call to a remote object executes in a new thread". That is, I still cannot understand what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Let's say the RMI implementation is single threaded.  Then how could each call not block other calls?

Comment: @danb "how could each call not block other calls" - very easy: run each call on a separate thread. This is not a problem. Usually a problem is to coordinate execution of parallel threads, but earlier you said " I am not really asking about how to coordinate dependencies, as I as aware of how to do that".
So, I still do not understand what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Keep in mind that the rmi call must return a result to the client caller. So lets say rmi is single threaded.  If you make a remote call, the rmi implementation executes the db statement in a thread (blocking any  other call). Spawning multiple threads does no good.  Am I missing something here? It's not each statement that is executing in parallel but rather multiple statements must be executed in parallel.  Therefore the RMI implementation must be multi-threaded. It must generate a thread per call (up to a limit perhaps)

Comment: @danb  RMI implementation does not generate a thread per call because a user can easily do this himself. This is not a problem. And why are saying "Spawning multiple threads does no good" and at the same time " RMI implementation must be multi-threaded". This means that you claim "RMI implementation must be no good". Very strange.

Comment: Actually it appears that various RMI implementations do generate a thread per call, however, the Oracle RMI implementation does not appear that to be configurable.  I was suggesting that it is important to know how the various RMI implementations generate threads and to be able to configure it. In an extreme case if the RMI implementation uses one thread for all calls then each call would block all other threads. Spawning a thread would not help, because the RMI call needs to return a result so it would have to wait for the spawned thread to complete and would still block.

Comment: @danb Most RMI implementations use a thread over *connection,* and use connection poling. So in general it is very difficult to state whether or not there is a thread per remote call. If they succeed each other quickly enough at the client so that the connection pool operates, there isn't.